# program schedule reminder with shell bash script

Tags: bash, shell, alarm

I wrote script about schedule reminder, but this program can't display when i set time. the script overall is right i think, but it's still error. please help me, whats wrong with my script.
thanks.
I'm sorry about my english

```
   nama=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter your name:" --entry-text " ");
   date=$(zenity --calendar --text "choose your event's day" --date-format=%A-%B-%Y);

   tang=$(zenity --forms --date-format=`date | awk ‘{print $1 $3,$2,$6}’ `| time :`date | awk '{print $4}'` );

    nambah=$(zenity --forms --ok-label="Done" --cancel-label="Cancel" --height=100 \
--title "Time" \
--text "Input Time(format 24)" \
--add-entry "Input Hours:Minutes:Second");

  text=$(zenity --text-info --title "create event" --editable --font=Purisa);

 a=1
 while (a==1)
 do
 cek="`date | awk '{print $4}'`";
 if [ "$nambah" == "$cek" ]
 then
 echo -n
 d=`echo "Time: $nambah"`
 fi
 done

 out=$(zenity --info --text "REMEMBER!! $nama today is $date you have event $d

 $text ");
```

Comment: and the error is ?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st problem come from the fact that your `cek` is never equal to your `nambah`(`17:00:00`) transform your `cek` assignation to

```
cek="`date +%H:%M+%S`";
```

Then you also need to **compare the date** in the `if` statement **not only the time**!

```
date=$(zenity --calendar --text "choose your event's day" --date-format=%Y%m%d);
```

In your loop:

```
cektime="`date '+%H:%M+%S'`";
cekdate="`date '%Y%m%d'`";
if [ "$nambah" == "$cektime" -a "$date" == "$cekdate" ]
```

Last but not least, you also need to add a `break` in your active waiting loop

If you compile everything your code becomes (you can remove the `echo` after testing):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nama=$(zenity --entry --text="Enter your name:" --entry-text " ");
date=$(zenity --calendar --text "choose your event's day" --date-format=%Y%m%d);

tang=$(zenity --forms --date-format=`date | awk ¥{print $1 $3,$2,$6}¦ `| time :`date | awk '{print $4}'` );

nambah=$(zenity --forms --ok-label="Done" --cancel-label="Cancel" --height=100 \
--title "Time" \
--text "Input Time(format 24)" \
--add-entry "Input Hours:Minutes:Second");

text=$(zenity --text-info --title "create event" --editable --font=Purisa);

a=1
while (a==1)
do
    cekdate="`date '+%Y%m%d'`";
    cektime="`date '+%H:%M:%S'`";
    echo "echo cektime: $cektime"
    echo "echo cekdate: $cekdate"
    echo "nambah: $nambah"
    echo "date: $date"
    if [ "$nambah" == "$cektime" -a "$date" == "$cekdate" ]
    then
        echo -n
        d=`echo "Time: $nambah"`
        break
    fi
done

out=$(zenity --info --text "REMEMBER!! $nama today is $date you have event $d $text ");
```

However I would recommend to change the active waiting with some `cron`